# My website is showing apache2 test page

Tags: website

My website that I use xenforo for stopped working and shows the apache2 test page.
Also the domain/admin.php does not load and shows the page including raw PHP code (rather then the results after interpreting the PHP code).

```
<?php
$startTime = microtime(true);
$fileDir = dirname(__FILE__);
require($fileDir . '/library/XenForo/Autoloader.php');
XenForo_Autoloader::getInstance()->setupAutoloader($fileDir . '/library');
XenForo_Application::initialize($fileDir . '/library', $fileDir);
XenForo_Application::set('page_start_time', $startTime);
$fc = new XenForo_FrontController(new XenForo_Dependencies_Admin());
```

What is wrong with it and how do I fix this?

Comment: I disagree. The problem does not seem to be the code, but rather that it does not get parsed by PHP. [SO] is about the code (which is fine).

Comment: Maybe I need to add some more. If I try to display a text file in a browser then I will usually see the results. If I try to display a HTML file then I will see the locally parsed results. (To verify that save `index.html` as `index.txt` and open it. You will see the raw HTML code as text). PHP does something similar but the parsing is done on the web-server. Except in the OP's case it does not work. So either the PHP installation on the server is broken, or it is not registered properly to Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Your Apache configuration may have been reset.

You need to tell it to pass `.php` files to your PHP executable as a handler for .PHP extensions.  [This](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) should give you the details and what you need to change.

Namely:

> Tell Apache to parse certain extensions as PHP. For example, let's
>   have Apache parse .php files as PHP. Instead of only using the Apache
>   AddType directive, we want to avoid potentially dangerous uploads and
>   created files such as exploit.php.jpg from being executed as PHP.
>   Using this example, you could have any extension(s) parse as PHP by
>   simply adding them. We'll add .php to demonstrate.

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
 SetHandler application/x-httpd-php 
 </FilesMatch>
```

You also need to be sure Apache is loading your PHP module with this:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```